# Supporting Larger Litter Size In Rabbit-Women With Minimal Deviations?

Tags: biology, reproduction

I had an idea for a race that is humans alchemically fused with various animals. One of the sub-varieties is rabbit-people, who have the famed bunny fertility. How might the bodies of the women be better adapted to carrying and giving birth to larger batches of children on average with as few deviations from the human body plan as possible?

Comment: define larger. 2x or 12x or higher?

Comment: As your name suggests, you have a fairly specific bias to your questions.

Comment: It would surely help your questions if you'd put some effort in following up the comments you receive on them (also referring to your past questions)

Comment: "Few deviations" requires some kind of measurement that you haven't defined. For example, I measure all human deviations by fingernail-growth-rate, with the standard being rather arbitrary...so most folks (including me) measure too far off and really shouldn't be considered 'human' in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Twin pregnancies do exist in humans. They are normally OK-ish, though some doctor would prefer to avoid them.

Carrying more than two babies is increasingly dangerous with the number of babies, and normally results in a early delivery via C-section.

The "issue" with the woman body which makes multi-baby pregnancies risky is the limited volume available to the womb and the limited breadth of the birth channel.

A necessary change would be the birth term: no longer 9 months, but earlier, so that the body of the baby is smaller, allowing for an easier delivery and less energetic burden on the mother.

Then I would argue that erect posture should be abandoned: she-rabbits can allow their wombs to expand to the side and to the bottom, while humans are constrained by the hip bones and the erect position on how much the waist can enlarge.

Last but not least, breastfeeding more than a baby with just a pair of glands would be unfeasible. The body should have more pairs than it has in homo sapiens.

Comment: This, in a nutshell, is the problem. If you want lots of babies per pregnancy, they have to be small relative to the mother. Trying to stuff (for instance) 9 typical human babies into one womb would require that womb to be able to occupy more or less the entire chest area. You know, where all those unimportant things like the heart and lungs and stomach are. Having that extend out from the body would produce an absurdly large bulge, such that it would be hopeless to remain upright for balance and weight reasons; you'd be confined to bed for most of the pregnancy, which is bad for health.

Comment: @Palarran Interesting points. So with a few evolutionary-behavioural tweaks to care-dynamics for the pregnant to accomodate a prolonged period of what basically amounts to complete disability, and similar tweaks for the care of even more helpless babies, it may be at least somewhat feasible to have k-selected humanoids. It wouldn't be particularly pretty, but it might work. If you want to go further with male care for females you could broaden the hips even further to the point that they're not very efficient at all for running, but much easier for childbirth.

Comment: @Ynneadwraith, please note that childcare and mothercare developed way after the species. Until a couple generations ago it was common for pregnant women to farm the fields until the very last days, as not working hands (and mouths) were a burden.

Comment: @L.Dutch Agreed in our species (although I'm not convinced about childcare being post-homo sapiens). For alchemically-fused rabbits (or more realistically for another sapient species with a different evolutionary past), the childcare aspect could easily develop well in advance of the dawn of our fictitious species. I'll grab some examples later, but there are many animals who exhibit total dependency of the female on the male during pregnancy, particularly in birds.

Comment: @Ynneadwraith, I should have said "maternity leaves" rather than childcare.

Comment: @L.Dutch Ah gotcha. I'd expect both maternity leave and paternity leave to be such an evolutionarily ingrained practice among the ancestors of our k-selected humans as to make it unquestionable whether you receive it or not. Unless they somehow manage to socially foist the burden onto the expectant mother's family members...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with L. Dutch on several points:

1. Shorter pregnancy.
2. More nipples/teats than just the one pair. If mum is giving birth to multiple babies, then lots of them have to be able to suckle at the same time. If they can't then either (a) Mum spends pretty much all day feeding them two at a time and she starves to death as she doesn't have any time to obtain food for herself, or (b) some of the babies starve, as they never get their fair share of her milk. Rabbits have 4 or 5 pairs of nipples, so can feed 8 to 10 young at once.

I'd add:

- Make the babies smaller and more even more helpless than human babies. Rabbit babies are blind and deaf at birth. The more development that goes on outside the womb, the faster you can prepare the womb to conceive another batch.
- The babies are going to have to learn to walk, talk and wipe their own bottoms much, much quicker than humans do. Mum cannot physically carry 8 toddlers about unless you want to make her super strong or give her a pouch like an oppossum. Human-rabbit people will be as agile as baby monkeys at a very young age.
- To really have a rabbit rate of reproduction, the kids have to be completely independent of Mum at a very early age. So either they become sexually mature much, much younger than humans do, or perhaps Dad takes over raising them as soon as they can walk.
- Humans are rubbish at getting pregnant (relatively speaking). It takes us a long time - an average of 6 months for newly-weds who are actively trying for a child. One of the reasons rabbits and hares get pregnant fast is that they are [reflex ovulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_ovulation_(animals)). The female ovulates in response to mating, so that there is always an egg for the sperm to meet.
- There is therefore no need for the female to keep males attracted to her when she is not in heat (oestrus). Sex for fun is unnecessary, as rabbits don't have to do it as frequently to guarantee a pregnancy. Rabbit-women will therefore be uninterested in sex for large portions of the year, and have no need to have the secondary sexual characteristic of permanently swollen breasts to attract rabbit men. Their breasts will be small and will only swell when they have new babies to feed. Even then, they are likely to be saggy rather than something out of an advert for WonderBra.
- If she's got so many babies to feed, Mum's body fat may fluctuate wildly. She needs to pile on the pounds to have enough fat to provide rich, rabbit-style milk for a whole litter of babies. She'll gradually lose weight until they are all weaned. So she may look anorexic by the time the litter is weaned, and have to feed up again before she can do it again. Rabbit-women who are ready to mate will be plump or obese to human eyes.

Lots of babies and helpless babies does mean that parental care becomes a problem. As does education. Rabbits can churn out dozens of offspring because they don't have to dedicate any time and effort to teaching them how to make stone tools, or make pottery or read, write and do accountancy or to study medicine. Mrs Rabbit can fill an entire school just with her own offspring and the teachers don't have any time to educate anyone else's kids!